# Numpy's 'where' function behaving ambiguously

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, correlation

I am trying to create a pandas dataframe that describes the NULL value percentage for each feature in my training dataset and also gives a correlation coefficient for each numeric feature with respect to the dependent variable. Here is my code:

```
#Count nulls and compute share
null_cols = pd.DataFrame(train.isnull().sum().sort_values(ascending = False))
null_cols.columns = ['NullCount']
null_cols.index.name = 'Features'
null_cols['Share'] = np.round(100 * null_cols['NullCount'] / len(train), decimals=2)

#Compute correlation of each numeric feature with respect to the dependent variable
for row in null_cols.index:
    print(row, np.where(is_numeric_dtype(train[row]), str(train['Dependent Var'].corr(train[row])), ''))
    #print(row, np.where(is_numeric_dtype(train[row]), str(train[row].isnull().sum()), ''))
```

On running this, I get TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int'. I think this error is coming from the corr function but why is it running that in the 'where' function for a non-numeric data type. Shouldn't it fall into the else?

The commented line of code i.e.

```
print(row, np.where(is_numeric_dtype(train[row]),str(train[row].isnull().sum()),''))
```

runs fine without an error and the 'where' function works as expected.

Comment: No, `numpy.where` is not the same as an if-else construction. It is passed entire arrays from which to choose values based on a condition, so those arrays need to be calculable for both the `True` and `False` conditions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's review how Python runs this code:

```
np.where(is_numeric_dtype(train[row]), str(train['Dependent Var'].corr(train[row])), '')
```

`where` is a function.  Python evaluates all arguments to a function before passing them to the function.  So it evaluates:

```
is_numeric_dtype(train[row])
str(train['Dependent Var'].corr(train[row]))
''
```

before calling `where`.

If you can only run `corr` on certain types of values, `np.where` is not the tool to use.  I think you need:

```
for row in null_cols.index:
    if is_numeric_dtype(train[row]):
        print(row, str(train['Dependent Var'].corr(train[row])))
    else:
        print('')
```